# Returning an empty string if the enum constant is not found

Tags: java, spring-boot

Suppose I have an enum class of

```
public enum ValueType {
    time("15"),
    post("15"),
    comment("F"),

    private final String valueType;

    ValueType(final String valueType) {
        this.valueType = valueType;
    };

    public String getValueType() {
        return this.valueType;
    }
}
```

and Im getting the constant value using

```
ValueType.valueOf(dynamicValueString).getValueType()
```

Supposed there is no enum constant for that dynamicValueString.

How can I set the value to an empty string if the enum is not found? without using try catch?

Comment: Why without a `try`-`catch`?

Comment: Keep a private static `HashMap` of string values to their enum keys, and use #getOrDefault; that is, if this is truly your performance bottleneck. You'd want to make a new, exception-free method to retrieve a constant for this. I think an Optional or `null` return would be much better, however, because an empty string won't be forced to be handled or fail miserably if it isn't handled via NPE (respectively). An NPE indicates you have a code error somewhere, you shouldn't ever hide an error, but instead fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd argue that you are right to avoid exceptions for normal program flow. Anyway, I use a map as suggested in comment:

```
public enum TestType {
    ONE("1"),
    TWO("2"),
    THREE("3");

    private final String str;

    TestType(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    private static final Map<String, TestType> MAP = Arrays.stream(values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(TestType::name, Function.identity()));

    public static String typeByName(String name) {
        TestType type = MAP.get(name);
        return type == null ? "" : type.str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum ValueType {
    time("15"),
    post("15"),
    comment("F");

    private final String valueType;

    ValueType(final String valueType) {
        this.valueType = valueType;
    }


    public String getValueType() {
        return this.valueType;
    }

    public static String getValueType(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(ValueType.values())
                .filter(v -> name.equalsIgnoreCase(v.valueType))
                .findFirst()
                .map(v -> v.valueType)
                .orElse("");

    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this? Because im getting only an empty string

Comment: method works fine, it returns string valueType by other string or empty string

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom lookup on your enum:

```
public enum ValueType {
    
    //...

    public static String lookupValueType(String constant) {
        try {
            return ValueType.valueOf(constant).valueType;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

And just use `ValueType.lookupValueType(dynamicValueString)` (I'm assuming `dynamicValueString` is meant to match enum value names)